# Jenkins - How to run one housekeeping job on all nodes (slaves + master)

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins setup of 6 Slaves and master, all windows machines. Now I have a housekeeping Jenkins job which I want to periodically run on all the slaves and master, as this job does following tasks

- Delete unused temporary files.
- Delete unwanted processes, as some of the tests are leaking processes (why leak is different question).
- Set certain environment variables, as sometimes I want to push environment variable changes to all machines.

Any idea how can I force Jenkins to run this one job on all slaves and master once every day? As a work around I can create multiple Jenkins job and mark each one to run on one particular slave or master, but I would rather avoid having so many duplicate jobs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Node and Label Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) allows you to parameterize where a job should be run. The job can be run on more than one node -- each node shows up as a separate execution in the job's build history. When multiple nodes are selected, you can configure whether the job should continue to run on other nodes if an execution fails.

Comment: If you select a label, does it run on every node with that label or just one?

Comment: @mjaggard If you select Label, there is a checkbox for "Run on all nodes matching the label", so you can select the appropriate behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar need, but using the [Node and Label Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) didn't seem quite right, as I do not want to parameterize my cleanup jobs.

I found a more satisfying answer in this post and thought it would also benefit to this question: [Jenkins - Running a single job in master as well as slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214501/jenkins-running-a-single-job-in-master-as-well-as-slave).

Here is some documentation on how to configure a "Matrix project": https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project.

What you are looking for is the "Slave axis". It's not very well documented in the page above, but it appears as an option of the "Add axis" menu whenever there are more than one node. Here's a screenshot of the interesting part:

[image: Configuration matrix using the slave axis]

Comment: Don't I now have to remember to come back to all my cleanup jobs when I add a new node?

Comment: Hum, that's a good point (at least for those managing jobs manually). Worth mentioning now: I'm using the [JobDSL plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) to generate all my jobs. Aside from my job dsl script, I have some other configuration which includes the nodes. I then generate system jobs for each. So that's why it was more appropriate in my case.

Comment: @mjaggard you can select labels (see screenshots). just configure a label there and remember to add that label to the node.

Answer (score 3):

Updates according to recent Jenkins

[image]

Pipeline type:
[image]

On "Configuration" page for pipeline:

[image]